# How to sort by condition using the mongo driver in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I've been following the mongo driver (2.4) documentation and am currently stuck trying to put a conditional on a sort.

Following the documentation, I got a AsQueryable instance and used the where function with an expression passed in. That works fine until the moment I want to order by a conditional instead of a field.

Here's what I'd like to order by:

```
db.child.AsQueryable().Where(expression).OrderBy(x=> x.parentId == someParentId);
```

which should be something along the lines of in linq

```
SELECT * FROM child
ORDER BY
  CASE parentId
  WHEN someParentId THEN 1
  ELSE 2 END,
  parentId;
```

Currently, however, after running the OrderBy condition I believe it's evaluating the expression because from the debugger I can see the expression change as shown below:

[image]

So the two main questions are:

1. How do I sort by an boolean expression using the .net mongo driver.
2. Why is the expression being converted as seen in the screenshot?

[Mongo Driver Documentation (2.4)](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/crud/linq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MongoDB C# driver documentation states (from pasted link):

> The driver contains an implementation of LINQ that targets the **aggregation framework**.

So there has to be a corresponding operation in Aggregation Framework to get translated from LINQ. You call `.AsQueryable()` which means you can build your expression using LINQ syntax but then it fails when needs to be translated to Aggregation Framework. Unfortunately you can't have expressions inside [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) and that's why your code will fail.

To fix that you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) stage to add one addional field `MatchesParent` and the sort by this field.

Assuming your model is represented by following class:

```
public class Model
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    // some other properties
}
```

you can add following class:

```
public class ModelResult: Model
{
    public bool MatchesParent { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can define `$addFields` as `PipelineStageDefinition` and `nameof` operator to keep it strongly typed:

```
PipelineStageDefinition<Model, ModelResult> addFields = new BsonDocument() {
            { "$addFields", new BsonDocument() {
                    { nameof(ModelResult.MatchesParent), new BsonDocument() {
                        { "$eq", new BsonArray() { "$" + nameof(Model.ParentId), someParentId } }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

var result = Col.Aggregate()
                .Match(expression)                           
                .AppendStage(addFields)
                .SortByDescending(x => x.MatchesParent)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks @mickl!